# Typescript passing Function as parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet

I'm trying to pass two functions as parameters, in order to customize a layer visualization for a Leaflet map. Apart from the specific case, which may not be relevant here as i'm asking for a more general concept, what i've done is:

```
Map.createLayer(function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  var popupContent = "<p>I started out as a GeoJSON " +
  feature.geometry.type + ", but now I'm a Leaflet vector!</p>";

  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
  }

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
},
function pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
  return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
  })
});
```

where the method "createLayer" of Map (which wraps a Leaflet Map) does:

```
public createLayer(popupContent:(feature, layer) => void, renderPoint:(feature,latlng) => L.CircleMarker): ICOLayer{
  this.layer = L.geoJSON(this.datasource.get(), {
    style: function(feature) {
      return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
    },
    onEachFeature: popupContent,
    pointToLayer: renderPoint
  });
  return this;
}
```

this doesn't work and i don't know why, but if i pass them as anonymous functions (thus ignoring the input parameters) everything works fine:

```
public createLayer(popupContent:(feature, layer) => void, renderPoint:(feature,latlng) => L.CircleMarker): ICOLayer{
      this.layer = L.geoJSON(this.datasource.get(), {
        style: function(feature) {
          return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
        },
        onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = "<p>I started out as a GeoJSON " +
            feature.geometry.type + ", but now I'm a Leaflet vector!</p>";
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
              popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
            }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        },
        pointToLayer: function pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
          })
      }
      });
      return this;
    }
```

I've also tried removing the signature of the functions in input, passing them as mere variables, but it didn't work,
I am not familiar with javascript/typescript, thus this might be a stupid error. Pardon me in advance.

EDIT: No error message is displayed while executing the first approach

Comment: Are you getting any error in first approach?

Comment: An error message is always more helpful than "doesn't work", so remember to share one if you have it.

Comment: Post edited, no error message is getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have really identical code in both cases. One problem I can imagine here - scope problem. `L.circleMarke` - (*when having the code block in your first example*) the `L` variable is not defined. But moving code inside module where `createLayer` method is - you get `L` reference, I assume, from imports.

Second question would be, why you don't get an exception about undefined `L`. I can assume, somewhere in code, there is a `try..catch` statement, which swallows the exception.

Run your code in chrome with developer tools opened and with `pause on caught exceptions` option on.  [image]

Also, you can put breakpoints inside functions for two cases, to ensure the functions are being called.